# How to prevent a vinegar taste when poaching eggs (using vinegared water)

Tags: sugar, vinegar

How does one remove the vinegar taste from eggs that are poached in water with vinegar added? Would rinsing the eggs in a sugar solution help?

Comment: Sugar counters the acid taste, but not the smell of vinegar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean eggs that have been poached in water with vinegar added?

I usually add vinegar to my poaching water when making poached eggs. However, I rarely taste the vinegar. I would suggest

- Use less vinegar. I use no more than a tablespoon for a shallow frying pan's worth of water
- Use a milder vinegar like white wine vinegar, or even lemon juice
- Use really fresh eggs if you can, in which case you don't even need vinegar

Lots of people use a saucepan full of water to poach eggs. I used to, but always with inconsistent results. Usually the egg white would just disintegrate and form a foam.

Now I use a small, shallow frying pan. This means the egg white has less opportunity to disintegrate, and also means I need to use less vinegar to help the white set.

If rather than poaching you mean *pickling*, there's little you can do to remove the vinegar taste, as the vinegar will have penetrated the egg thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks ElendilTheTall, actually what I did was for each egg, I put one tablespoon. Never thought that I can use lemon juice to replace vinegar. Maybe a lemon egg will taste better?

Comment: Most of the lemon flavour is in the zest, so you shouldn't notice too much of a lemony taste, if any.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall, clearly you've never had a truly ripe lemon. While unquestionably the zest contains a concentrated amount of flavor, the juice of a tree-ripened lemon will have a lovely fresh and fragrant flavor of its own (i.e. while we associate both the juice's flavor and the zest with "lemon", they don't actually taste very similar).